# TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, face-detection, opencv, cascade

I'm currently working on opencv - bluring the russian vechile plates but I am getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCqcL.jpg) everytime I run the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    result = detect_plate(img)
  File "C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/test.py", line 26, in detect_plate
    cv2.rectangle(plates,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),7.5)
TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

what problem is it?
i did load all the images and xml files properly

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('car_plate.jpg')



def display(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(img)
display(img)



plate_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml')

def detect_plate(img):
    plates = img.copy()
    plate_rect = plate_cascade.detectMultiScale(plates)
    
    for (x,y,w,h) in plate_rect:
        cv2.rectangle(plates,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),7.5)
    return plates

result = detect_plate(img)
display(result)



def detect_and_blur_plate(img):
    plate_copy = img.copy()

    plate_rect = plate_cascade.detectMultiScale(plate_copy)

    for (x,y,w,h) in plate_rect:
        plate_img = plate_copy[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        plate_img = cv2.medianBlur(plate_img,8)
        plate_copy[y:y+h,x:x+w] = plate_img
    return plate_copy

result = detect_and_blur_plate(img)
display(result)
```

kindly help me I'm a beginner

Comment: the error says the function takes 4 arguments and you are providing it with 2, I would try to move the expressions out and store them in individual variables, and then pass the variables as function arguments, that may clarify what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue open on OpenCV git board. You can check it here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15465

Comment: spelled out: the solution is to make sure you pass integers because some of those values might be floating point numbers. just say `int(some_number)` in the arguments to the function. x, y, w, h, or the last argument (7.5) could be causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually because of non-int values in coordinates `(x,y)` of `cv2.rectangle(plates,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),7.5)`

Solution is :

```
x = int(x) 
y = int(y)
w = int(w)
h = int(h)
```